# Am I using NSTimer correctly in iPhone View-based app?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm working on a simple proof-of-concept for an iPhone app (and important bit of info, I'm pretty new to Mac OSX development all around).  I created a view based app with a timer.  I declared my NSTimer in the interface of my app's controller, used @property and @synthesize, and I initialize it in the controller's viewDidLoad method with scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval method.  My selector is a method with the signature `-(void)someMethod:(NSTimer *)timer` which is declared in the interface and defined in the implementation file of the controller as well.  I can step past the line where I assign the timer and see that it points to a valid object, but my program goes no further than the end of the viewDidLoad method and never reaches the breakpoint at the first line of my method that is called by the timer.  Also, I see `GDB: Program received bad signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"` in the status bar of xcode at this point (viewDidLoad end is reached).  I didn't do anything in IB but add a view and a picker just so I'd see if the UI actually loads...it never does.

So, am I doing something wrong with the NSTimer, or are my troubles elsewhere?  How can I use the debugging tools in xcode to get more information?

Comment: Can you post some code? You're probably passing the wrong selector to the NSTimer, or not using @selector.

Comment: Also, the stack is the most useful tool in understanding an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (which is fancy-talk for "chased an illegal pointer"). What line of code were you on when you actually crashed? If you were in a framework at the time, what was it doing?

Comment: Looks like you fogot ":" when create selector 
It mus be:  

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target: self selector: @selector(someMethod:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` usually indicates a memory management error, without seeing the code probably from somewhere else in your app. It's a very common error for beginners, but an important subject to fully understand, so I'd suggest looking through some of the questions on memory management here and find a few guides or tutorials to look through. It's actually pretty easy to learn.

Also, it shouldn't hurt but unless you need to access the timer in between fire events, you don't actually need to store it as an instance variable. Once you create and start a timer it's added to and retained by the application's run loop.

Comment: Thanks.  I stripped out everything else but the timer and some very basic code in my timer's selector, and everything works and all breakpoints are hit.  The issue is indeed elsewhere in this method and I'm sure it has to do with memory mgmt as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Have you got NSZombieEnabled?

Might be useful if this is failing on an over released object.

Comment: This is a very good piece of advice. NSZbomieEnabled was very useful to me, along with clang.